# 2 Observers and must return one of them according to value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm a beginner in Angular, I'm working with Angular 4 and Ionic 3.
I got a method that should return an Observable.

In this method I have to pick the good Observable between 2 according to the value of the first.

I tried multiple ways to perform it but I take issue with the asynchronism.

The following code not working because of the asynchronism but I do not found another way.

```
let obs: Observable<T>;
let localFile: FileBase64Model;
/* This will get my first observer I got to check his value */
obs = this.localDataBaseSrv.getQualityCheckpointFile(fileId) as Observable<T>;
    return obs.pipe(
      map(file => {
        // If observer value is not true I got to return another observer
        if(!file) {              
          // I cannot return observable here, so I'm trying to get value of other observable and put it in my observable that will be return
          this.get(`/${fileId}`, undefined, body).subscribe(value =>     localFile = value as FileBase64Model);
        } else {
          return file;
        }
      }),
      map( file =>  {
        // When code is here, the localFile is not yet complete because of asynchronous subscribe method !
        if(!file) {              
          return localFile;
        } else {
          return file;
        }
      })
    );
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
obs = this.localDataBaseSrv.getQualityCheckpointFile(fileId) as Observable<T>;
    return obs.pipe(
      mergeMap(file => {
        // If observer value is not true I got to return another observer
        if(!file) {              
          return this.get(`/${fileId}`, yourOptions);
        } else {
          return of(file);
        }
      })
    );
```

This is using a flattening operator, mergeMap so that you don't return an Observable of an Observable when you do a `get()` request, also it serves your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I did not get that mergeMap was able to return an Observable !